# Attachments are missing when multiple files are attached in mail

Tags: find, email, mailx

I have written one script to get multiple attachments through mail. My script is

```
for file in `find $dir -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"`
do
echo "$file"
filename=`basename $file`
echo $filename -exec uuencode {} {}\;|mailx -s "North" abc@gmail.com
echo "$filename"
done
```

But I am getting mail without attachments. Please help me what is wrong in this.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `uuencode` is not standard and won't give you attachments. If you want to send a mail with multiple attachments, the easiest solution may be to use Mutt with `mutt -s subject -a file1 file2 ... filen -- address < message`

Comment: vinc17 Thank you but in my machine i do not have mutt and i could not install this as i am using client machine. Is there anyway without using mutt?

Comment: You can first ask the sysadmin to install `mutt`. If he can't / doesn't want, have a look at: http://backreference.org/2013/05/22/send-email-with-attachments-from-script-or-command-line/ (if you don't have the `base64` command, use `uuencode -m` or `uuencode --base64` instead).

Comment: @Aravind it was standard. Back in the 1980s and early-ish 1990s. We've moved on since then (as shown in this answer) and attachments are manged through MIME.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tip that shows how to use `uuencode` to append multiple attachments to a single file, and then attach this single file to the email. The article is titled: [Email Multiple File Attachments From Solairs / AIX / HP-UX / UNIX / Linux Command Line](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-sending-files-as-mail-attachments/).

#### Example

```
$ uuencode r1.tar.gz r1.tar.gz > /tmp/out.mail
$ uuencode r2.tar.gz r3.tar.gz >> /tmp/out.mail
$ uuencode r3.tar.gz r3.tar.gz >> /tmp/out.mail
$ cat email-body.txt >> /tmp/out.mail
$ mail -s "Reports" you@cyberciti.biz < /tmp/out.mail
```

Comment: ♦ Thank you, but i dont want append files into a single file. Multiple should be send as attachment with out zipping

Answer (score 0):

Here, use this :).

```
#!/bin/bash
RECIP="abc@example.com"
SRCDIR="yourdirectory"
TMPDIR="tmp"
[ ! -d "$TMPDIR" ] && mkdir -p "$TMPDIR"

attargs=""
for file in `find "$SRCDIR" -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"`; do
    echo "$file" #DEBUG
    filename=`basename $file`
    uuencode "$file" "$filename" > "$TMPDIR/${filename}"
    attargs="${attargs} -a $TMPDIR/$filename"
done

echo "mailx -s \"Done\" ${attargs[@]} $RECIP" #DEBUG
echo | mailx -s "Done" ${attargs[@]} "$RECIP"
```

Afterwards delete the temporary dir, which contains all the uuencoded files.

Make sure you decode them with `uudecode`.